# Extracting data from html using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I an trying to extract data from a website using beautifulSoup. I want to extract data from this HTML Snippet

```html
<ul class="result-info info-bro-6 cc" style="display: block;">
            <li>
                <strong>MODERATED</strong>
                <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
Health                        </li>
                        <li>
C****                        </li>
                        <li>
C*******                        </li>
                        <li>
D****                        </li>
                        <li>
Di8****                        </li>
                        <li>
Di****                        </li>
                        <li>
F*******                        </li>
                        <li>
Fi******                       </li>
                        <li>
L******                       </li>
                        <li>
M****                        </li>
                        <li>
NM*****                        </li>
                        <li>
P******                        </li>
                        <li>
Pr*****                        </li>
                        <li>
Sp****                        </li>
                        <li>
*******e                        </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

                    <li>
                <strong>
                    *********
                </strong>
                <ul class="cc">
                        <li>***   /****</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

The data i want to extract is "***    /****". I want my code to return this and only this, however the code i currently have is returning all the data within the li tags. How could i extract only the data i want?

This is my current code:

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = """<ul class="result-info info-bro-6 cc" style="display: block;">
            <li>
                <strong>H*******</strong>
                <ul class="cc">
                        <li>
H*****                        </li>
                        <li>
C****                        </li>
                        <li>
C*******                        </li>
                        <li>
D****                        </li>
                        <li>
Di*****                        </li>
                        <li>
Di****                        </li>
                        <li>
F*******                        </li>
                        <li>
Fi******                       </li>
                        <li>
L******                       </li>
                        <li>
M****                        </li>
                        <li>
NM*****                        </li>
                        <li>
P******                        </li>
                        <li>
Pr*****                        </li>
                        <li>
Sp****                        </li>
                        <li>
*******e                        </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

                    <li>
                <strong>
                    *********
                </strong>
                <ul class="cc">
                        <li>***   /****</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'cc'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
             print(litag.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, there are a bunch of `ul` tags with `class=cc`. You'll need to find a consistency in your HTML that'll allow you to grab that one and that one only.

For example, the `ul` tag you want is the last one in your HTML. So instead of iterating through all the `ul` tags, just get the last one:

```
ultag = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'cc'})[-1]
litag = ultag.li
print(litag.text)
```

Unfortunately, if this doesn't work because there are more `ul` tags later on in your HTML code, then you'll need to make your navigating more specific.

---

If it is the last `ul` in the class `result-info info-bro-6 cc`, then perhaps this will help:

```
outer_ul = soup.select_one('ul.result-info.info-bro-6.cc')
last_ul = outer_ul.find_all('ul')[-1]
print(last_ul.text)
```

Comment: I should've been more specific in my question, the whole HTML has a lot more ul tags later on, i also need to extract data from those, is there any way for me to specify the length of data to bring back using beautiful soup?

Comment: @PythonNewbie Try and figure out how to get that last `ul` only - for example, is it always the last `ul` in `ul class="result-info info-bro-6 cc"`?

Comment: It is always the last UL in each ul class="result-info info-bro-6 cc". I am relatively new to both python and stack overflow so please ask if you need clarification

Answer (score 0):

you can use `next` to find the next sibling of that tag

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class':'cc'})[2].next.next.text
print(data)
```

Comment: Should probably consider adding some description to the answer. While code-only answers are not against the rules, the answer may not occur as clearly to the OP as to you, so some explanation is always welcome

Comment: sorry i forgot to add